# snowflake convert 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ[UTC]' to timestamp

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have strings in the following two formats:
`'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ[UTC]'` and `'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmZ[UTC]'`.

Here is how I convert them

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING(timeStampString, 1, CHARINDEX('[UTC]',timeStampString) - 1)) AS myTimestamp
```

I wonder if this will work

```
coalesce(
    TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(dateString, 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmZ[UTC]'),
    TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(dateString, 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ[UTC]')
) AS myTimestamp
```

So far, no luck. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MIZ[UTC]`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(dateString, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MIZ[UTC]'),
                TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(dateString, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ[UTC]')) 
       AS myTimestamp
FROM (SELECT '2002-02-12T12:14Z[UTC]' AS dateString UNION ALL
      SELECT '2000-05-05T15:16:17Z[UTC]');
```

Output:

```
MYTIMESTAMP
2002-02-12 12:14:00.000
2000-05-05 15:16:17.000
```